# Random spreading

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, cellular-automata

Given an infinite grid of squares, some marked alive (which stay alive forever,) some marked dead at any time(like Conway's game of life) and 1 alive at the beginning, there is an algorithm. It starts with a list of the living cells, which does not change through an execution. It goes through each cell, and with a probability $p$, will choose one of the 8 surrounding cells one that is dead to make alive. Two living cells can not select the same cell. Every surrounding dead cell is equally likely to be chosen. If it is completely surrounded by living cells, it will not spread. After $t$ executions of the algorithm, on average how many cells will be alive in terms of $t$ and $p$.

(Note: If you know a better way to restate this question, please do so. I am not familiar with problems of this type and so do not know the best way to state it.)

Comment: You write "one of the $8$ surrounding dead cells". But even if the original configuration had each living cell surrounded by $8$ dead cells (which you didn't state), eventually this wouldn't be the case. I suspect that you meant "one of the dead cells among the $8$ surrounding cells"? Also, you didn't specify how the "choosing" is done; presumably one cell is chosen uniformly among the dead cells among the surrounding cells?

Comment: Your edit addressed the first part of my comment but not the second.

Comment: Are we assuming that finitely many cells start alive?  Otherwise the question "on average how many cells will be alive" needs to be better characterized.

Comment: Two clarifications: first, do the living cells stay living forever? Second, consider the starting configuration with exactly two living cells at $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$, so that $(1,1)$ is a common neighbor. During the first execution, is it possible for $(1,1)$ to be chosen for each of $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$? Or would its being chosen as a neighbor of $(0,0)$ preclude it from being chosen for $(2,2)$ that round?